# Continuous function from Lp space

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Are the functions from Lebesgue measurable $Lp$-space continuous? I want to know this. Can any one answer me please ?

Comment: Of course not. take characteristic functions of sets of finite measure.

Answer (score 0):

They don't have to, but they can. A function $f\in L^p$ has to verify that

$$ \|f\|_{L^p} =\left(\int |f|^p\right)^{1/p}<\infty. $$

But notice that this allows $f$ to be discontinuous even in a dense set of points. For example in $[0,1]$, if we define $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\in(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})\cap [0,1]$, then

$$ \|f\|_{L^p[0,1]} = \left(\int_{[0,1]} |f(x)|^pdx\right)^{1/p} = \left(\int_{(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})\cap[0,1]} |f(x)|^pdx\right)^{1/p} = 0<\infty. $$

Comment: This is not a good example, as $L^p$ usually denotes a.e. equivalence classes of functions and your $f$ is equivalent to the zero function, which is continuous. When one speaks of a function $f\in L^p$ being continuous one typically means that they have a continuous representative in their equivalence class. A better example is given in Kavi Rami Murphy's comment above.

Comment: I know $L^p$ denotes a.e. but I didn't know the notion of equivalent class in $L^p$ was implicit in the question, I thought it could be referred to any kind of discontinuity. Anyways, I apologize if the example doesn't help.